# CI- Deploy mule projects with Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, continuous-integration, mule

Is possible to deploy mule projects with Jenkins using Maven?

All Mule projects are in a repository in subversion and the job can checkout that repository, but is possible to run that projects in a mule runtime?

Answer (score 1):

Use the mule maven plugin and deploy it through Jenkins.

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/mule-maven-plugin

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to deploy mule projects with Jenkins using Maven. It will same as any other deployment using Jenkins with Maven.